# multiple regression models results from a list in R

Tags: r, loops, regression

I performed multiple regression results in R and save them in the environment as `a list of ncol(data)`, to display one of the regression results and it's `summary` i use this command `summary(lm_results[[1]])`, which prints the following

```
Call:
lm(formula = fml, data = data)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.1615 -0.9830 -0.3605  0.3508  4.5893 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.04464    0.91212   0.049 0.961506    
X2           0.34424    0.08067   4.267 0.000464 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.975 on 18 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.5029,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.4753 
F-statistic: 18.21 on 1 and 18 DF,  p-value: 0.0004637
```

I want to print all the regression results in one command like
`for(i in 1:ncol(data))  Regress[i] <-  summary(lm_results[[i]])`

and also to be able to extract only all R-squared or Adj R-square values of all regression models (and format them in one dataframe) . How can i do that in R?

Comment: `lapply(listofmodels,summary)`

Comment: @Duck Can i only display R-squared values of the models instead of all summary?

Comment: Yes, try this: `lapply(listofmodels,function(x)summary(x)[8])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try any of these approaches (I have used some simulated data):

```
#Option 1
lapply(listofmodels,function(x)summary(x)[8])
```

Output:

```
$model1
$model1$r.squared
[1] 0.01382265


$model2
$model2$r.squared
[1] 0.9271098
```

Or:

```
#Option 2
lapply(listofmodels,function(x)summary(x)[['r.squared']])
```

Output:

```
$model1
[1] 0.01382265

$model2
[1] 0.9271098
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
listofmodels <- list(model1=lm(iris$Sepal.Length~iris$Sepal.Width),model2=lm(iris$Petal.Width~iris$Petal.Length))
```

Comment: thanks, i used the `lapply` option #1, an put them in a data frame `as.data.frame(lapply(listofmodels,function(x)summary(x)[8])))` . How can i change the `colames` to have *X1,X2,..,Xn* instead of *r.squared1., r.squared.2,...,r.squared.n*?

Comment: @nickolakis Hi. You can use after create the dataframe this code `df1 <- as.data.frame(lapply(listofmodels,function(x)summary(x)[8])))` after that use `names(df1)<-paste0('X',1:dim(df1)[2])` Let me know if that works!

Answer (score 1):

We could `tidy` or `glance` the model output with `broom` and extract the relevant component

```
library(broom)
library(purrr)
map_dfr(listofmodels, tidy)
```

---

To extract only the 'r.squared'

```
map_dfr(listofmodels, ~ glance(.x) %>%
                            select(r.squared))
```